# Not able to compute alpha in image

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, halide

I trying to write simple image computing program using Halide. So I start with brightness function.

**I got this**

```
Halide::ImageParam img(Halide::type_of<float>(), 3);
img.set_stride(0, 4);
img.set_stride(2, 1);
Halide::Func f;
Halide::Var x, y, c;
Halide::Param<float> brightnesMod;

f(x, y, c) = img(x,y,c) * brightnesMod;

f.vectorize(x, 16).parallel(y);

auto & obuff = f.output_buffer();
obuff.set_stride(0, 4);
obuff.set_stride(2, 1);
std::vector<Halide::Argument> arguments = { img, brightnesMod };
f.compile_to_file("function", arguments);
return 0;
```

but then I have a problem. My image is RGBA image so I compute algorithm with alpha. How can I skip it, and change f(x,y,c) to make c only 0-2?

Answer (score 1):

That would mean that you want the output extent of c to be 3. It's the same as any other dimension: it has a minimum and an extent. Your input is RGBA, so 4 channels - its c extent is 4.

how many color channels will be produced, depends on the extents you request when you call the pipeline.

You could use:

```
obuff.set_extent(c, 3);
```

If you want to force the amount of channels to 3, which would result in an error if you try to request more or less than 3 channels.

Answer (score 0):

As Sander said, you simply have to ask for the 3rd dimension to be of extent 3 instead of 4, in this case by passing in an output buffer with extent 3 in that dimension. You probably also want to set the *stride* over the color channels to 3 (set_stride(0,3) in your example, since you seem to want interleaved RGB data) if you only want a 3-channel output buffer. If you want an RGBA output buffer but with alpha ignored during computation, you'd leave the stride at 4 but set the extent to only 3.

Another note: using planar, rather than interleaved, storage will give much better performance for vectorizing over the x dimension like you are doing here. In general, vectorization works (by far) best over the innermost/densest storage dimension, especially for a computation this simple.

Comment: so... if i understand you correct I shoud change f.vectorize(x, 16).parallel(y); to something else?